# How to upload angular application with server side coding to web server like hostgator?

Tags: angular, express, sockets, server, peer

I need to upload my angular web application to hostgator web server. My application contains both client and server side code. I am able to upload client side code successfully and it’s working. But coming to server side code I didn’t understand how to upload to web server. This server code developed in JavaScript and it used the node packages. Used express, socket.io, http, peer services in server code. How to upload client and server codes together to web server. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to run as part of a Node app, depending if  you are using cPanel or Plesk, you can achieve this:

cPanel: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Install+a+Node.js+Application

Plesk: https://www.plesk.com/blog/product-technology/node-js-plesk-onyx/

---

For plesk itself it's quite straightforward, install an extension through the GUI and configure it by telling it which command to run on startup.

Comment: If you have any issues feel free to add a comment, especially if you're using plesk as I have worked with it  to deploy node applications in production.